# Swift, iPhone simulator strange grey cover over tableView

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have no experience with ObjectiveC, I am practising swift programming, my program works with no error.
In my detail View Controller I have added tableview and a tableview cell
When I run I check there is data come back but there is a strange grey cover over my table view as shown in following screenshot, I have tried remove table view and even View Controller it still come back. What I possibly done wrong or this is bug of beta version? I am using beta 5

[image: Sceenshot]

Answer (score -2):

below the code clear the tableview background  color check attachment for example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8qHU.png)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```